# Highlight row of NSOutlineView

Tags: c#, cocoa, mono, xamarin, monomac

I have a project in MonoMac/Xamarin.MAc written in C#. In it I have a custom class derived from NSOutlineView which shows a context menu for some items. By doing it this way instead of just assigning the Menu property (which would show a context menu for *every* item) I lose the blue border which appears around the row when you right-click an item (I call it a highlight, as opposed to a selection which is a solid blue). You can see this in action by right-clicking any item in the sidebar in the Finder window.

Is there a way to programmatically highlight a certain row of an NSOutlineView? Note that the actual selection is still left intact.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:-

```
[outlineView selectRowIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:index] byExtendingSelection:YES];
```

Comment: is there a swift conversion to this?

Comment: This modifies the selection and does not produce the blue border asked for in the original question.